# Deleting devexpress bar on designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress

This has to be an easy one. I've got a form and I can't see one of the Dev Express bars on the designer surface. How do I find it and remove it without manually going in and delete the designer code.

Answer (score 0):

View menu -> Properties Window and you should see at the top of the Properties Window, a dropdown list of elements.  Select it in the list, then select the designer tab in the main window to move focus back there, and press the Delete key.

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but this means I have to go through the designer code manually, right, deleting all references to the deleted control?

Comment: It should update the auto-generated designer partial class code, if that is what you mean.  If it's not, I'm not sure what you are asking.